# How to redirect the output of a command as the quickfix list to a vim server / function?

Tags: linux, invocation, quickfix, clientserver

When I click on a link in thunderbird and firefox is already running, it doesn't open a new window, just a new tab.

I want the same thing for vim: no matter where I am and how I send a bunch of files to it, I want them opened in a single session.

To do this, I've added the following code in my `~/.bashrc` and `~/.zshrc`.

```
function nv {

vim --serverlist | grep -q VIM

if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then

    if [ $# -eq 0 ]; then
        vim
    else
        vim --remote "$@"
    fi

else
    vim --servername vim "$@"
fi

}
```

It defines the function `nv` which can do 3 things :

- if no VIM server is running, `nv` launches one
- if a VIM server is
  running and one or more arguments were passed to `nv`, it sends them
  to the server
- if a VIM server is running but no argument was passed
  to `nv`, it launches a simple vim session (so that I can still launch a separate vim session by using the same function / alias)

---

I've recently [read](https://www.reddit.com/r/vim/comments/3u23ro/vim_q_ftw/) that you could redirect the output of a shell command as the quickfix list to vim. For example :

```
vim -q <(grep -Rn foo *)
```

It works with vim but not with my function `nv`.

I would like to use the same syntax so that the output of `grep` is not opened by a new vim session, but by the VIM server.

When I use `nv -q <(grep -Rn foo *)`, the VIM server doesn't receive the output of `grep` but a file called `-q` and another one : `/proc/<pid>/fd/11`.

I know why it doesn't work, the function was not written with that case in mind.

But then, I tried something simpler : `vim --remote -q <(grep -Rn foo *)`

And the result is the same, it doesn't work, the server still receives two files : `-q` and `/proc/<pid>/fd/11`.

I would like to know if it's possible to edit the code of my `nv` function so that it works when I use it with the `-q` switch to remotely populate the quickfix list of an already running vim server, and if so receive some advice on how to do it.

If it's not, at least, I would like to know how to use the `-q` and `--remote` switch simultaneously.

---

**Edit** : I may be wrong but I don't think `-q` and `--remote` can be used simultaneously.

For the moment, I've come up with the following command :

```
vim --remote-send ":grep -Rn foo *<cr><cr>"
```

Now I need to edit the `nv` function to integrate it, but I don't know how to do it.

Edit bis: I don't think it's worth the trouble, I'll stick with `nv` and the last command when needed.

Comment: I'll post the answer later on. Let's see if someone else builds a better solution in the meantime.

Comment: I have not much experience with `--remote` arguments, but you should get something to work, if in your function you check for the argument `-q` and then use `--remote-send ":cexpr $1<cr>"` or something like this. That should work, but as I said, I don't know for sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use `--remote` with `-q`, any arguments after `--remote` are treated as filenames:

```
--remote    Connect to a Vim server and make it edit the files given in
            the rest of the arguments.  If no server is found a warning
            is given and the files are edited in the current Vim.
```

That said, you cannot use the result of process substitution (`<(cmd)`) with a program running elsewhere. If you notice, the file name from process substitution uses `/proc/self`:

```
$ echo <(date)
/proc/self/fd/11
```

The shell sets up the file descriptors of the executed command so that one of them points the substituted process. Naturally, this `fd` cannot be easily used by a separate process - you'll at least need to translate `/proc/self` to `/proc/<PID>`.

Therefore, it would be easier if we could run the command in Vim itself. The [`cexpr`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/quickfix.txt.html#%3Acexpr) command should help us there:
quickfix.txt  For Vim version 7.4.  Last change: 2015 Sep 08

```
                                                        :cex :cexpr E777
:cex[pr][!] {expr}      Create a quickfix list using the result of {expr} and
                        jump to the first error.
                        If {expr} is a String, then each new-line terminated
                        line in the String is processed using the global value
                        of 'errorformat' and the result is added to the
                        quickfix list.
                        If {expr} is a List, then each String item in the list
                        is processed and added to the quickfix list.  Non
                        String items in the List are ignored.
                        See :cc for [!].
                        Examples: 
                                :cexpr system('grep -n xyz *')
                                :cexpr getline(1, '$')
```

Huh, one of the examples uses `grep` much the same way you do.

Using `cexpr`, the following function could work:

```
function nv (
    if vim --serverlist | grep -q VIM; then
        if [ $# -eq 0 ]; then
            vim
        elif [[ $1 == -q ]]; then
            shift
            IFS=' '
            vim --remote-send ":cexpr system('$*')<cr><cr>"
        else
            vim --remote "$@"
        fi
    else
        vim --servername VIM "$@"
    fi
)
```

Use it thus:

```
nv -q grep -Rn foo *
```

That's to say, you pass the command as you would write it to `nv -q`. The function checks if the first argument is `-q`, and then uses `vim --remote-send` to call `cexpr` and `system()` on the rest of the arguments.

This bit might need explaining:

```
shift
IFS=' '
... system('$*') ...
```

Since the first argument is `-q` and it's no longer needed, and using `$*` is more convenient, I simply discard `-q`.

Now, there are two quick ways of combining the arguments: `$@` and `$*`. A quoted `$@` is usually preferred, if you want separate words (we don't). So, we use `$*`, which combines the arguments using the first character of `IFS`. What the value of IFS is depends on the shell, so I set it to a space to get the needed effect.

The best effect is if you send a quoted command:

```
nv -q 'grep -Rn foo *'
```

Then `*` won't be expanded by the shell you called it from, thus preventing problems when called by `system()`.

#### Note

My [earlier version](http://paste.ubuntu.com/13516374/) of the function used `{}` to group the command. This version uses `()`, to create a subshell. This makes it easier to set variables like `IFS` locally without disturbing the shell.

Comment: Nice explanation ! The only thing hard to understand for me was the special parameter '$*'. There seems to be a sort of chain : original shell > vim > system() function > another shell, and they all inherit the environment of the first one otherwise the last shell wouldn't be able to expand '$*' correctly. Thanks for your thorough explanation.